# Not able to install docker on redhat

Tags: docker, redhat, rhel7

I searched for many links, they are showing only for centos even though the title is for RHEL also.

My OS details:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)

```
uname -r
```

> 3.10.0-693.58.1.el7.x86_64

I ran this to add repo

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/docker-ce.repo
```

THen this

```
sudo yum install docker-ce
```

But giving this error.

> Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos
> https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml:
> [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found Trying other mirror. To address
> this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article
>
> https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623
>
> If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a
> ticket with Red Hat Support.
>
> rhel-7-server-rpms
> | 3.4 kB  00:00:00 rhui-microsoft-azure-rhel7-eus
> | 2.1 kB  00:00:00 rhui-rhel-7-server-dotnet-rhui-rpms
> | 2.3 kB  00:00:00 rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-optional-rpms
> | 1.8 kB  00:00:00 rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms
> | 2.0 kB  00:00:00 rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-supplementary-rpms
> | 2.0 kB  00:00:00 rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms
> | 2.1 kB  00:00:00 rhui-rhel-server-rhui-rhscl-7-rpms
> | 2.0 kB  00:00:00 Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.12-3.el7 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: docker-ce-cli for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.13-3.2.el7 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.2.el7.x86_64
> ---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.12-3.el7 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64
> ---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.12-3.el7 will be installed
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
> Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
> Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
> ********************************************************************** yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily
> enabling disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies. To
> enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in
> /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
>
> ---
>
> Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
> Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.12-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
> Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Docker CE currently requires RHEL/CentOS 7.6 or higher. You will need to upgrade the OS from 7.4 before continuing.

Comment: I tried on RHEL 8 now, still same issue

Comment: @UdayKiranReddy If you were on RHEL 8, it would either succeed, or have a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the centos repositories instead of Redhat. Just disable the repository you just added with `yum-config-manager --disable repository` and run,

```
# yum  -y remove  docker-common docker container-selinux docker-selinux docker-engine
# yum -y install lvm2 device-mapper device-mapper-persistent-data device-mapper-event device-mapper-libs device-mapper-event-libs
# yum -y install  wget
# wget https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
```

Enable the rhel-7-server-extras-rpms repository,

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```

and finally,

```
yum -y install docker-ce
```

Comment: last step getting this error.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ukreddy-erwin/openstacklogs/master/04-06-2020/rheldockerlog

Comment: last step getting this error.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ukreddy-erwin/openstacklogs/master/04-06-2020/rheldockerlog

So, I installed this, 
sudo yum install https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch.rpm

,But still, same error

Comment: can you please run rpm -q container-selinux

Comment: getting output as container-selinux not found

Comment: The container-selinux package is in the rhel-7-server-extras-rpms repo, enable it by

subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms

Comment: enabled but getting these errors
when I tried https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ukreddy-erwin/openstacklogs/master/04-06-2020/rhellog1

Comment: can you please run subscription-manager repos --list-enabled

Comment: +----------------------------------------------------------+
    Available Repositories in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo
+----------------------------------------------------------+
Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/extras/os
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/os
Enabled:   1

Comment: it is expecting selinux-policy=3.13.1-216.el7 but installed 3.13.1-166.el7_4.9 even if i intall again it is giving this version only

Comment: you can check here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272827/docker-ce-on-rhel-requires-container-selinux-2-9 to install the package manually

Comment: It raises again a different error.

Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch (/container-selinux-2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch)
           Requires: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-216.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.12.1-153.el7.noarch (rhel-7-server-rpms)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove old packages.

```
yum  -y remove  docker-common docker container-selinux docker-selinux docker-engine
```

Comment: yes Kishore, I did but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Install `container-selinux` from centos mirrors and try installing `docker-ce` again.

Reference:
http://ksssblogs.blogspot.com/2020/07/installing-docker-on-rhel-centos.html

Answer (score 0):

to fix that follow below steps in addition to

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -i container-selinux-2.107.el7.noarch.rpm
 
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/slirp4netns-0.4.3-4.el7_8.x86_64.rpm
 
#Set up the Docker CE repository on RHEL:
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum install -y device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum makecache fast
yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
#Start Docker:
sudo systemctl start docker
 
#Test your Docker CE installation:
sudo docker run hello-world
```